# Error Alsa arecord: set_params:1233:

Tags: pi-2, alsa, pixel

Does anybody know how to fix this error? Or where I can edit it so it includes the sample format?

```
arecord -d 4 test.wav
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
```

Answer (score 1):

The default sample format of `arecord` was chosen for backwards compatibility with Sun workstations, not for being useful.

Specify the sample format you actually want to use,e.g., `-f dat`.

Comment: Well this did something the result was a massive  drop of asci in the terminal window. And could not stop it via ssh or in the vnc terminal on my pi.
Was this the recording I saw in asci?

Comment: Did you omit the file name?

Comment: Now I did that with        arecord -d 10 -f cd -t wav -D copy foobar.wav
but I get file not found

Comment: Omit the "-D copy".

Answer (score 0):

You can define sample format with `-f`. You have only one format available: `S16_LE`. So you can get your command working with: `arecord -d 4 -f S16_LE test.wav`